ReactJS and Firebase:TypeError while uploading files to firebase storage
I am getting the following error while trying to upload files to Firebase Storage:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Following is my firebase SDK:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...
  authDomain: ...
  databaseURL: ...
  projectId: ...
  storageBucket: ...
  messagingSenderId: ...
  appId: ...
  measurementId: ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

// }

export { database, auth, app, firestore, storage };


The following is the the upload functionality of the app:
import {
  getDownloadURL,
  ref as storageRef,
  uploadBytes,
} from "firebase/storage";

.
.
.



const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setImage(file);
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    if (!image) {
      console.error('No image selected');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const imageRef = storageRef(storage, `images/{user.uid}/{image.name}`);
      uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert("failure");
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("failure below");
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    }
  };

.
.
.

<div>
    <input type="file" onChange={handleImageChange} />
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleUpload}>Upload Image</Button>
</div>

Also after uploading the file onto Storage I want to get the downloadURL as I want to push the same onto the database. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated!

Can you also share the error in detail? The stack trace would be great to pin point where exactly the error is occurring. Also, please share that code as well.
